# QMainWindow default selecting a QPushButton(Focus)

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4

I'm in a bit of a bind because I have been experimenting on creating a GUI with pyqt4 through python.

In `QDialog` when you open a window, it automatically **focus** on a `QPushButton` and you can press `Tab` to cycle through the `QDialog` and press enter on the selected `QPushButton` or `menuBar` etc. **but** how do I do it on `QMainWindow`? Setting

`button1.setAutoDefault(True)`

does work but cycling selection in `QMainWindow`(with `Tab`) **does** select other `Qbject` **but** pressing enter does not work

**unless** I re-select the `button1` through `Tab`(`Enter` only works on the default `button1`). I've tried reading the documentation but maybe I missed something?

Here's my code:

```
class Window(QtGui.QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Window, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setGeometry(750, 450, 400, 200)
        self.setFixedSize(self.size())
        btn1 = QtGui.QPushButton("OK", self)
        btn1.clicked.connect(self.trans_num)
        btn1.resize(btn1.minimumSizeHint())
        btn1.move(210,171)
        btn1.setStatusTip("Magic")
        btn1.setDefault(True)
        btn1.setAutoDefault(True)

        btn2 = QtGui.QPushButton("Exit", self)
        btn2.clicked.connect(self.close_application)
        btn2.resize(btn2.minimumSizeHint())
        btn2.move(305,171)
        btn2.setStatusTip("Exit Application")
        self.show()
```

Comment: You could show your code, since your explanation is unclear.

Comment: check my post, I added a code and tried to clarify the question

Comment: You describe a QDialog in your question but in your code I do not see it.

Comment: You describe a Tab but I do not see it either.

Comment: I think you missed it or my english is bad, anyway, pressing tab in a keyboard selects something right? so pressing tab on any application will cycle my selection and select something by pressing the enter in the keyboard. `QDialog` selects a default button for me automatically on `show()` but not `QMainWindow`. and setting `setAutoDefault` in `QMainWindow` does it but I can't cycle selections through `tab`

Comment: Okay, now I understand, you mean the tab key, as I was working on a previous question where QTabBar was used and QTabWidget related it :P . If you want to just open the QMainWindow the focus this on that QPushButton, am I correct?

Comment: I'm confused with your reply but if you mean focusing on a specific `QPushButton`(or selecting it automatically) on `show()` of `QMainWindow` then yes.

Comment: I've added setDefault (True) to all the buttons and it works, have you tried what I tell you?

Comment: It highlights both buttons and the enter only works on both. Upon searching I now know what you meant by `focus` and I will rephrase my question. I want to focus on a specific button upon `show()` of `QMainWindow`.

Comment: Ey bro, I think I get it now I have to set `.setDefault(True)` and `.setAutoDefault(True)` to set what button i would like to be highlighted/focused on `show()` then add `.setAutoDefault(True)`only to the rest of the objects inside my window. Thanks bro :)